# Event from dynamically used backbone template control not firing

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I need to display div based on user's choice : one, two or three. If one is chosen, only one div will be populated from backbone template. If two, two divs will be populated and for three, three divs will be populated. First one is populated at backbone initialization phase. The problem is, a select control from first div which is loaded from template at initialization phase will fire its change event. But other two div's select control don't fire. My code structure is as follow:

```
    <input type="radio" name="chooseRadio" value="1" checked="checked" /> Choose 1
    <input type="radio" name="chooseRadio" value="2" /> Choose 2
    <input type="radio" name="chooseRadio" value="3" /> Choose 3
    <div id="locations">
        <div id="divLoc1">
        </div>
        <div id="divLoc2">
        </div>
        <div id="divLoc3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/template" id="template1">
        <select id="select1" class="added-later">
            <option value="test1">test 1</option>
            <option value="test2">rest 2</option>
        </select>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var loc = Backbone.Model.extend({
                current: 1,
                template: _.template($('#template1').html()),
                events: {
                    'change #select1': 'onSelectChange'
                },
                onSelectChange: function () {
                    alert('yes');
                },
                initialize: function () {
                    var loc1 = this.template();
                    $('#divLoc1').html(loc1);
                    $(this.loc2).hide();
                    $(this.loc3).hide();
                },
                maintainLocations: function () {
                    alert(this.current);
                    switch (this.current) {
                        case '1':
                            $('#divLoc2').hide();
                            $('#divLoc3').hide();
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            var loc1 = this.template();
                            $('#divLoc2').html(loc1);
                            $('#divLoc2').show();
                            $('#divLoc3').hide();
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            var loc1 = this.template();
                            $('#divLoc2').html(loc1);
                            $('#divLoc3').html(loc1);
                            $('#divLoc2').show();
                            $('#divLoc3').show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            var appView = new loc();

            $('input[name=chooseRadio]').click(function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                appView.current = val;
                appView.maintainLocations();
            });

            $('#select1').change(function () {
                alert('fired!');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

I am using backbone 1.1.2. Any idea please?

Comment: A Backbone view can receive events from dynamically generated DOM elements, through the events property, as long as the dynamically generated DOM elements are descendants of the view's `el`.

Comment: But @chridam I am using Model here, not view.

Comment: Why are you using a model as though it was a view? [The documentation](http://backbonejs.org) is pretty clear that views have `events` and interact with the DOM, not models. Your code doesn't work because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: As I have realized, the Model above should be View and the $el element should be specified. After that I can detect events from $el and all its children and take the actions accordingly. I think I messed model and view concept in the question. Not bit clearer of myself. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because when you wire up an jquery event handler, it wires up the handler only for the existing elements inside the DOM.

For every new DOM element you insert [or is inserted], you must reinvoke the event handler wiring code.

For e.g.

```
    function wireUpHandlers() {

      $('input[name=chooseRadio]').click(function () {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    appView.current = val;
                    appView.maintainLocations();
                });

                $('#select1').change(function () {
                    alert('fired!');
                });


    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        wireUpHandlers();
    });
```

Now, whenever you add new HTML in to your page, invoke wireUpHandlers() again and the handlers will work for the new elements added too.

Comment: Your way works, besides wireUpHandlers() cannot get out of document ready block. However I am looking for backbone way. Could you suggest the same for my case? Thanks.

Comment: According to my understanding, backbone and jQuery event handlers dont go on the same path.. Hence, i dont see any BACKBONE way to do so. Because there's no way you can make jQuery aware of the binding the event handlers to the dynamic HTML elements appended by Backbone